# How do I make a pyspark udf with optional variable and mandatory inputs

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a python egg file and want to use it as a pyspark udf to apply to spark dataframe

```
class MY_TEST(object):
    def __init__(self, df_in):
        self.df = df_in

    def TEST_FUNCTION(self, type, col1=None, col2=None, col3=None):
        if col1:
            col1 = col1
        else:
            col1 = self.df['col1'].get_values()[0]

        if col2:
            col2 = col2
        else:
            col2 = self.df['col2'].get_values()[0]

        if col3:
            col3 = col3
        else:
            col3 = self.df['col3'].get_values()[0]

        if type=='add':
            final = col1 + col2 + col3
        else:
            final = col1 * col2 * col3


        return final
```

when I run on my machine:

import pandas as pd

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame()
df_in['col1'] = [1]
df_in['col2'] = [2]
df_in['col3'] = [5]

df_in['col1'] = df_in['col1'].astype(float)
df_in['col2'] = df_in['col2'].astype(float)
df_in['col3'] = df_in['col3'].astype(float)

MY_TEST_init = MY_TEST(df_in)
print('add                 ', MY_TEST_init.TEST_FUNCTION('add'))
print('add Col1 manipulate ', MY_TEST_init.TEST_FUNCTION('add', col1=5))
print('mult                ', MY_TEST_init.TEST_FUNCTION('mult'))
```

Results are like this (as expected):

```
add                  8.0
add Col1 manipulate  12.0
mult                 10.0
```

However, when I tried to put it into pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import size, lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("<PATH>-MY_TEST.egg")
import MY_TEST as MY_TEST

df_in = pd.DataFrame()
df_in['col1'] = [1]
df_in['col2'] = [2]
df_in['col3'] = [5]

df_in['col1'] = df_in['col1'].astype(float)
df_in['col2'] = df_in['col2'].astype(float)
df_in['col3'] = df_in['col3'].astype(float)

sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_in)
df_spark = df_spark.withColumn("test", lit('add'))

MY_TEST_init = MY_TEST.MY_TEST(df_in)

TEST_FUNCTION_udf = udf(MY_TEST_init.TEST_FUNCTION, FloatType())
result = df_spark.withColumn('result', TEST_FUNCTION_udf(df_spark['test']))
```

I expected a result but got an error instead:

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 10 in stage 810.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 10.3 in stage 810.0 (TID 66758, 172.60.250.7, executor 47): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):